# How to find biggest last name in an Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array with elements in the following format. I need to find biggest last name but i dont know how to slice it into two elements if its array

```
let arr = ['Sergii Khromhenko', 'Sergey Kosarev', 'Sergey Sandul'];
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string by a space and get the second item to get the last name.

[`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) can be used to sort the array by the length of the last name. [`slice(-1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is used to extract the last item.

```js
let arr = ['Sergii Khromhenko', 'Sergey Kosarev', 'Sergey Sandul'];
const longest = arr.sort((a, b) => a.split(" ")[1].length - b.split(" ")[1].length).slice(-1)[0]
console.log(longest);
```

Alternatively, you can just iterate through the array and keep track of the item with the longest last name:

```js
let arr = ['Sergii Khromhenko', 'Sergey Kosarev', 'Sergey Sandul'];
var length = 0, longest;
arr.forEach(e => {
  const len = e.split(" ")[1].length;
  if (len > length) length = len, longest = e;
});
console.log(longest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

We can go through each item in the list and keep track of the longest we've found.

```js
let array = ["Sergii Khromhenko", "Sergey Kosarev", "Sergey Sandul"];

let longest = array.reduce((acc, name) => {
    let surname = name.split(" ")[1];
    return surname.length > acc.length ? surname : acc;
}, "");

console.log(longest);
```

**You can find more info on the methods I used here:**

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> **MDN Web Docs:**
> The `reduce()` method executes a **reducer** function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

> **MDN Web Docs:**
> The `split()` method divides a String into an ordered list of substrings, puts these substrings into an array, and returns the array.  The division is done by searching for a pattern; where the pattern is provided as the first parameter in the method's call.